# (Constant Crashes and BSOD)[fixed] FPS lag and infequent crashes when trying to run games windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, crash, graphics

I recently had to reformat my computer and prior to this reformat I was running GTA 5 perfectly fine on the highest settings, the settings that had been optimized by "The GeForce Experience", a software that comes with new graphics cards. Now after the reformat I am getting constant crashes after about 1 minute of the game being launched and I once even got the BSOD. I have installed all my up to date graphics drivers and have optimized the game through the geforce experience. What else could be going wrong? Is there something else that I will need to install? Are there other drivers that I am missing?

I have validated the steam files and the only difference from before is that I am running a newer, official version of windows 7 proffesional. I have also recently tested running other games and they also crash. Could this be a steam issue?

I downloaded AppCrashViewer and BlueScreenViewer if anyone would like to look over the crash information:

```
Application Name:   GTA5.exe 
Application Version:    1.0.335.2 
Application Timestamp: 5533cf03 
Fault Module Name:  StackHash_c23a 
Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0 
Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000 
Exception Offset:   0000000000000001 
Exception Code: c0000005 
Exception Data: 0000000000000008 
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
```

[image: This is the BSOD from the crash minidump]

--> About 5 days later 
I have since contacted EVGA and they said to send in the card for repair or replacement, but when I took it out and put back in my old graphics card I am still getting the same issues. I deduced from some error solving boards that it was in fact a graphics issue, and the odds of both the cards randomly breaking is also absurdly low, so I am to assume that it is a software issue.

--> About 1 week later
Thanks to MagicAndre's solution I am now able to play games without them crashing immediately. However now it is the much less severe issue of FPS lag. I am getting some choppy gameplay and still the occasional crash, on more games than just GTA(I have only experienced crashing on GTA so although that seems related it may not be, but I haven't played any other game as long so far). This choppiness is even in offline and is not ping related. Also in case anyone is curious about what else we have tried, there is another post with additional information. [Second post](https://superuser.com/questions/906886/graphical-issues-crashing-games-and-bsod-on-win-7-64bit)

Comment: which STOP code do you get when you have a BSOD? Shre the dmp files.

Comment: Where do I find those? My minidump is empty and bluescreenview shows nothing.

Comment: Windows needs a pagefile to create dumps. Make sure you haven't disabled the pagefile.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I added the picture for the BSOD. The crash code is labeled "Bug check code" and the four parameters under it.

Comment: Can you upload the actual dump file somewhere? It seemed that the graphics driver caused the problem but not sure without the dump. I would downgrade the graphics driver to something older with WHQL and double check if any of page file setting is changed. If you have multiple physical/logical drives, change the page file position to the other drive with no file size limit.

Comment: we need the actual dmp fiels to see more details. upload them on a cloud service and post the link here.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/042615-19874-01

Comment: did you remove the overclock on your cpu? even if you think that isn't it, you need to try it to rule it out

Comment: @Yorik he has a non K CPU (Intel  i5-3450), so he can't OC it.

Comment: @magicandre1981: the OP has several posts relating to this same issue, and in one, says "I have 8 gbs and I'm overclocking my cpu by a little bit." ( comment thread @ http://superuser.com/questions/906886 ) Whether this is possible or not, I have to accept it at face value.

Comment: I am overclocking my CPU about .4 GHz whether it's possible or not haha.

Answer (score 1):

The dump shows hardware issues:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff80002c7fb6f, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: fffff8800a990100, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------


SYSTEM_SKU:  SKU

SYSTEM_VERSION:  System Version

BIOS_DATE:  04/18/2012

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  P8Z77-V LX

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev X.0x

BUGCHECK_P1: c0000005

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff80002c7fb6f

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff8800a990100

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!KiSystemServiceStart+11
fffff800`02c7fb6f 0f0000          sldt    word ptr [rax]

CONTEXT:  fffff8800a990100 -- (.cxr 0xfffff8800a990100)
rax=0000000000000031 rbx=fffffa800cfbab50 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=00000000554af950 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80002c7fb6f rsp=fffff8800a990ae0 rbp=fffff8800a990b60
 r8=000007ffffed6000  r9=00000000554af9d0 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000246 r12=00000000554af950 r13=0000000000000001
r14=00000041a065d929 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
nt!KiSystemServiceStart+0x11:
fffff800`02c7fb6f 0f0000          sldt    word ptr [rax] ds:002b:00000000`00000031=????????
Resetting default scope

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: c79

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3a

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  GTA5.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10041.3 amd64fre

MISALIGNED_IP: 
nt!KiSystemServiceStart+11
fffff800`02c7fb6f 0f0000          sldt    word ptr [rax]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000000077a2df1a to fffff80002c7fb6f

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
02 nt!KiSystemServiceHandler
03 nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
04 nt!RtlDispatchException
05 nt!KiDispatchException
06 nt!KiExceptionDispatch
07 nt!KiPageFault
08 nt!KiSystemServiceStart
09 0x0


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!KiSystemServiceStart+11
fffff800`02c7fb6f 0f0000          sldt    word ptr [rax]

IMAGE_NAME:  hardware

MODULE_NAME: hardware

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_IP_MISALIGNED

BUCKET_ID:  X64_IP_MISALIGNED

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  X64_IP_MISALIGNED

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_ip_misaligned
```

I can see that your BIOS is a bit old (from 2012):

```
BiosVersion = 0607
BiosReleaseDate = 04/18/2012
BaseBoardManufacturer = ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoardProduct = P8Z77-V LX
```

[Download](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/1/39/7/6/wUVREuJSCNu0ys0i/30/) and flash the latest BIOS. Some newer BIOS version fix the stability:

> P8Z77-V LX BIOS 2501
>
> Improve system stability.

Comment: But what hardware is the question then?

Comment: and also how do I install the bois? Like what to download? just the bios and boot from it or is there something else I need?

Comment: check the User's Manual how you have to do the BIOS update

Comment: Okay I have updated the bios now what?

Comment: look if you still have the issues or not. If you still get crashes, post pictures (memory and SPD tab)of CPU-Z: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: so updating bios should have fixed my problems?

Comment: Look what happens. The text from the BIOS Update shows that this BIOS version improves system stability. Maybe it also fixes your issue

Comment: im not saying it's perfect but running some tests with games I got 2 crashes in about five hours. Much Much better than before. thanks a bunch

Comment: upload the new dumps

Comment: They're just game dumps. No more system crashes. I also have a bit of fps jittering across all games.

Comment: there is a new GTA5 patch: https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/de/articles/205086728--4-30-15-GTAV-PC-Patch-350-1-Notes Install it and look if it fixes the crashes.

Comment: It wasn't only on GTA, Dota 2 was also being jittery and I checked my ping and it was fine. It's that sort of choppiness where you can feel the game about to crash but the sound is still playing fluidly, and then sometimes it just goes back to normal and sometimes it crashes. The point is that although that was happening a little bit I still played for about 2 and half hours before a crash, so there is at least one big step up.

Comment: Start up resource monitor (resmon.exe) and pull up the disk tab, sort on the "response time" column. When it does what you describe above, alt-tab and check the disk response time. Check you event viewer for any disk related errors (bad blocks etc) that may have thrown during the last minute.