# Graphical issues (crashing games and BSOD on win 7 64bit)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, crash

I made this post about a week ago trying to get some help: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/904813/constant-crashes-and-bsod-when-trying-to-run-games-windows-7-64bit)
and since then have been able to narrow down a little what the problem is.

- The problem only arose after I reformatted my computer.
- I am very certain that it is a software issue and not hardware.
- I have uninstalled and re installed ALL drivers about 3 times. Separately and together
- I have contacted EVGA and they want me to send in the graphics card(which I'm fairly certain has nothing wrong with it.

The card is a GTX 960 and my old one was a GTX 560. If you feel as though I didn't give enough information please refer to my previous post.

Comment: Why are you assuming the issue is video?  It sounds like it could just as easily be GTA5?

Comment: I have tested it with Gta5, Dota2, Dying light, and Borderlands TPS. All of the crash. However when I run a low graphical intensity game like Binding of Issac it does not crash

Comment: Did you try a clean uninstall? That should be an option and it removes all driver traces first- supposedly, then restart and install again.

Comment: @DougWatkins How would I go about doing this? A clean uninstall of what? Any links would be appreciated.

Comment: @PinkMonkeyBird when you start the driver install for your card, there is usually a checkbox or some other option , maybe under advanced, to do a clean driver install.

Comment: @DougWatkins Fuck okay, I grabbed the disk but then remembered I have the old one in currently so I'd have to change them around again. Just to be clear before I go to all this trouble. You are suggesting that old drivers may be interfering with the new ones? That something might have gotten messed up after the reformat? Keep in mind it did work for 1 week perfectly fine prior to the reformat.

Comment: @PinkMonkeyBird - The games you mentioned vs Binding of Issac all use DirectX while I am pretty sure Binding of Issac isn't a DirectX game.  The simple fact is this.  If the problem existed before the format, and existed after the format, then its unlikely a driver problem and thus a hardware problem.  Even if it didn't crash before, and your using the current drivers, and you performed a clean installation then it still is very likely a hardware problem.

Comment: But then how do you explain the old graphics card also not working?

Comment: @DougWatkins Okay I have done the clean install of the graphics driver, but to no avail. Still crashing.

Comment: @PinkMonkeyBird since you say it stopped working after the reinstall, did you install newer drivers after the reinstall? You could try doing a clean reinstall of the drivers you had installed before the wipe. And like Ramhound said this does nothing if it's a hardware problem, which the timing of the issue could be coincidentally linked to the reinstall.

Comment: What would be the odds of the hardware working one week and then breaking inside my computer the next. And then a different card breaking outside my computer at the same time?

Comment: @PinkMonkeyBird I am with Ramhound, you cannot completely ignore hardware related issues. To me it seems like a memory related issue. Get a copy of MemTest86 from [here](http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) and do a RAM test. The reason is that, the games you have mentioned that are causing the crash GTA5, DOTA2 are not only graphics intensive but also memory intensive. Most of those have 4GB of RAM requirement. Sometimes faulty RAMs are not so easy to detect, until and unless your system is stressed out to a point. The RAM test will confirm that.

Comment: @Ayan that would make more sense because that would explain why neither card worked and I was also having some glitch with my old OS that would cause me to be using about 6 GB of RAM when I was just idol at the desktop.

Comment: hth, Is this a desktop or a laptop? Can you remove and put back the graphics card? If you have done clean uninstall, did you install basic drivers for windows only, install games and from there see if the game crash? Thanks,

Comment: @Ayan hey so I did the mem test and after a 7 hour scan(didn't realize it would take so freaking long) it came Back with no errors. Now I am at the information viewing screen and I'm just wondering is there any information I should specially be looking at here? Any where to go? What to look for that could be an issue?

Comment: I forgot to ask one thing. How much RAM do you have in your system? Now about the memtest results, I haven't used memtest for a long time so I forgot how they used to display the results. Normally from what I remember if something is wrong with the RAM, the address space responsible for it was highlighted in red. The total number of errors, tests run, etc. would be displayed in the summary. But since it did'nt reported any error I think your RAMs are fine. That at least eliminates one of the hardware suspects. BTW did you tweaked any of your BIOS settings?

Comment: I have 8 gbs and I'm overclocking my cpu by a little bit.